# VBA pass ie element to a function

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

As I am having getting difficulty in reliably checking ie.busy and ie.readystate to check that a web page has loaded, I have a function that checks for a particular element being present to confirm that the page has loaded.

The code below works, but is clunky in that I have to have a separate function for each page I call that I want to check.
I would ideally like to pass the line "ie.document.getElementsByClassName("container centered-form single-column clearfix")(0).innerText" to the function as a parameter so that the function can be used for any web page, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Many thanks

```
Function checkLoginUrl(ie As Variant, strMessageContent As String, compareString As String) As Boolean

        EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:22")
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 'wait a bit to start with as code falls here as too quick

        'get the value of the element we are monitoring
        dd = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("container centered-form single-column clearfix")(0).innerText

        Do While dd = ""
            DoEvents
            'recheck the value we are monitoring
            dd = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("container centered-form single-column clearfix")(0).innerText
            Printlog (Now & " - " & dd & " - and waited 3 secs")
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
            If StartTime > EndTime Then
                Printlog ("Tried to log on for 22 seconds without success")
            Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        'so dd should be populated now so check
        If dd Like "*" & compareString & "*" Then

            Printlog (strMessageContent & " loaded successfully")

            retval = True
        Else
            Printlog (strMessageContent & " failed to load")
            retval = False

        End If

    launchUrl = retval

End Function
```

Comment: Are you waiting for an element to be present or for an element to have a particular .innerText value? Subtly different.

Comment: Hi. I’m waiting for the element to have a particular inner text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps familiarize yourself with [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), where you can specify the pattern to match a node with as a string you then pass to the function. Simply the function a little as well, and ensure you are using consistent naming. Currently, you are not returning from your function due to the end assignment variable having a different name. For more flexibility also pass the wait time as a param.

The immediate advantages being you don't need to worry about all the different chained methods (getElementsBy....) and you are using a method that modern browsers are optimized for.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, url As String, result As Boolean
    Dim strMessageContent As String, compareString As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    url = "https://example.com"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "url"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        cssSelector = ".container.centered-form.single-column.clearfix"

        result = checkLoginUrl(ie, cssSelector, strMessageContent, compareString, MAX_WAIT_SEC) 'you might consider renaming 'result' as 'found' _
                               and move the final If statement out the function and have it following here ......

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function checkLoginUrl(ByVal ie As Object, ByVal cssSelector As String, ByVal strMessageContent As String, compareString As String, ByVal MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long) As Boolean
    Dim t As Date, ele As Object, dd As String, found As Boolean

    t = Timer
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ele = ie.document.querySelector(cssSelector)
        dd = ele.innerText
        found = InStr(dd, compareString) > 0
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop Until found

    If found Then
        Printlog strMessageContent & " loaded successfully"
    Else
        Printlog "Tried to log on for " & MAX_WAIT_SEC & " seconds without success"
        Printlog strMessageContent & " failed to load"
    End If
    checkLoginUrl = found
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to store the value of **ie.document.getElementsByClassName("container centered-form single-column clearfix")(0).innerText** in variable and pass string argument to your function by adding one more string parameter in function like below?

```
Function checkLoginUrl(ie As Variant, strMessageContent As String, compareString As String, element as string) As Boolean
```

Let me know, if I misunderstood anything from your above description. I will try to correct myself.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I have tried that, but it just sees the variable element as a string "ie.document.getElementsByClassName("container centered-form single-column clearfix")(0).innerText" as opposed to the actual value of the element itself.

Comment: I suspect I would need to somehow declare the variable element with a type other than string or variant(tried both). Something like element as Internetexplorer.element. Cant see how to do that.

Comment: But that line will return you the inner text which will be string so I am not sure how it is making any difference? Are you getting any error while using it or any other issue with it? or you are just passing that whole line of code in string variable?

Comment: Sorry. My comment may not have been clear. 

The function just sees the contents of the variable element as a string in its own right and simply passes that string to the next variable dd as a string of “ "ie.document.getElementsByClassName(("container centered-form single-column clearfix")(0).innerText" instead of actually grabbing the value of the element itself. 
I think I need to declare element variable sheri.southam@mail.com an object of some kind.

Comment: What I am saying that you assign the value of inner text to any variable outside the function and than pass that variable as a parameter of the function. So your function will have value instead of code as a string. Did you tried like this?

Comment: Ahah. I see. Sorry. Will give it a try. I suppose the problem would be the variable outside the function won’t update. Or if I declare it ByRef perhaps it might. 
Will give this a go.

Comment: If variable value get modified in function than you can keep the line of code in function and try to pass the class name and index number as a parameter will help to get latest value inside your function.

Comment: Many thanks, I now see how this could work, however, I have decided to use the css method submitted by Qharr as it is a very tidy solution and I had not been aware of the benefits off css. Thanks for your interest.